# ¿Cómo hago un efecto de perilla en CSS?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Quiero hacer un efecto de perilla en CSS, es decir hacer que una rueda gire con respecto a la posición del mouse cuando el usuario haga click sobre esta, pero no se como convertir las coordenadas X Y del mouse a grados para rotar un elemento usando, por ejemplo, la propiedad transform: rotate, por cierto esto:

[image: Perilla de un amplificador]

Es lo que yo conozco como una perilla, buscando información me di cuenta que lo llamand de formas diferentes en latinoamerica.

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que intentaste o investigaste, revisar [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo obteniendo las coordenadas del mouse y las del objeto div y luego aplicar un rotate en base a esas coordenadas utilizando Math.atan2, por ejemplo:

```js
// Creamos una función que obtenga las coordenadas de nuestro div
        function rotateDiv(element) {
            const {left, top, width, height} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {x: left + width / 2, y: top + height / 2}
        }

        // Seleccionamos el elemento
        const round = document.querySelector("#round");

        // Obtenemos las coordenadas
        const roundCenter = rotateDiv(round);

        // Detectamos cuando se mueve el mouse
        addEventListener( "mousemove", ({clientX, clientY}) => {
            
            // Obtenemos las coordenas del cursor con las del elemento div
            const angle = Math.atan2( clientY - roundCenter.y, clientX - roundCenter.x);
            
            // Aplicamos las coordenadas a nuestro elemento
            round.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}rad)`;
    
        });
```

```css
html  {
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        #round {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-image: url(https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/395/3/png-transparent-knob-switch-thumbnail.png);
            background-size: 278px;
            background-position: -38px -39px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="round"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias